# dropdown menu for content per page was not changed

Tags: puppeteer

Here is the source code of dropdown menu and I am trying to change it to 100 per page from default of 20.

```
<label class="control-label pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: 100;">

        <small>显示</small>&nbsp;
        <select class="input-sm grid-per-pager" name="per-page">
            <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=10" >10</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=20" selected>20</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=30" >30</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=50" >50</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=100" >100</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;<small>条</small>
    </label>
```

Here is my code for doing the selection and the code runs successfully without throwing error. I can watch the movement on the browser but it is still the 20 per page as selected and was not 100. Why the per page was not changed to 100?

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args:[
      '--start-maximized' // you can also use '--start-fullscreen'
   ]});
    const page = await browser.newPage(); 
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1600, height: 900});

 ...........
    await page.waitForSelector('select[name="per-page"]');
    await page.waitForSelector('select[name="per-page"] > option:nth-child(5)');
    .....
    await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by doing:

```
await page.goto("https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=100", {waitUntil: 'load'});
```